# Denoting surface integration

Tags: vector-analysis

I always denoted surface integration by $ \displaystyle \iint_{S}$, however while reading about flux I saw a surface integral as $\int_{S}$, therefore I am confused.

Comment: How would you denote the integration over a surface in $999$-dimensional space? Actually there is no hard restriction on which notation you should use, and if you don't want to emphasize that the integration is being carried out over a $2$-dimensional surface (it should be evident form the context), there is no need to write out the multiple integral sign.

Comment: The surface is in 2 dimensions as opposed to 3 dimensions, does that help?

Comment: It just appears that dS is defining how many integrals to use.... I didn't even exactly think of spherical coordinates when I wrote this either.